# Mysql JOIN of four tables with two key tables

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1066

I hate to admit it by my knowledge of MySQL is lacking when it comes to the more complex queries. Essentially I have four tables  two of them contain the data I want to return, and two are relational tables linking the data. `Table A` is present just to provide filler for `Table D.aID`.

```
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +-----------+ +-----------+
|Table A | |Table B | |Table C | |  Table D  | |  Table E  |
+---+----+ +---+----+ +---+----+ +---+---+---+ +---+---+---+
|aID|name| |bID|name| |cID|name| |dID|aID|bID| |eID|dID|cID|
+---+----+ +---+----+ +---+----+ +---+---+---+ +---+---+---+
| 1 | a_1| | 1 | b_1| | 1 | c_1| | 1 | 1 | 1 | | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+----+ | 2 | b_2| | 2 | c_2| | 2 | 1 | 2 | | 1 | 1 | 2 |
           +---+----+ | 3 | c_3| +---+---+---+ +---+---+---+
                      +---+----+
```

The relationship created with these tables is: `Table A > Table B > Table C`. The data I am wanting belongs to the `Table B > Table C` relationship.

```
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|tblB.bID|tblB.name|tblC.cID|tblC.name|
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|    1   |    a_1  |    1   |   c_1   |
|    1   |    a_1  |    2   |   c_2   |
|    2   |    a_2  |  NULL  |   NULL  |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

However to ensure I am following the correct path I need to grab the `Table B` of the `Table A > Table B` relationship `Table C` belongs to. I realize that I am making things much more difficult for myself by allowing for duplicate `name` values, but I would rather have small tables and more complex queries than bloated tables and simpler queries. The query I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM `Table E`
LEFT JOIN `Table D` ON (`Table B`.bID = `Table D`.bID)
RIGHT JOIN `Table E` ON (`Table D`.dID = `Table E`.dID))
RIGHT JOIN `Table C` ON (`Table E.cID = `Table C`.cID);
```

However so far it has not worked. When the query is submitted this error is returned:

```
ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'Table D'
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Is this even possible?

Comment: As you mentioned wanting simple queries (and since your key columns have matching names) you may wish to consider replacing `on (tablex.xID = tabley.xID)` with `using xID`.

Comment: I was not aware I could do that. Thank you for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Smith I was able to come up with the solution I am posting here. I hope this might be able to help someone else.

```
SELECT  tblB.bID,
    tblB.name,
    tblC.cID,
    tblC.name
FROM Table E 
RIGHT JOIN Table B ON (Table B.bID = Table D.bID)
RIGHT JOIN Table D USING dID
RIGHT JOIN Table C USING cID;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you say you are submitting bears little resemblance to the table structure you have given us! 
What is `Table D.national_regionID`? Or `modx.coverage_state`?

Generally though don't mix left and right joins. Also every table used in the query must either follow the `FROM` or follow a `JOIN`. You seem to be using `Table B` and `Table C` in join conditions without ever adding them to the query.

Comment: `Table D.national_regionID` and `modx.coverage_state` were remnants of the actual query left over from a failed search and replace. So you're saying the query should look something similar to this:

 SELECT * FROM `Table E`
 RIGHT JOIN `Table B` ON (`Table B`.bID = `Table D`.bID)
 RIGHT JOIN `Table D` USING `dID`
 RIGHT JOIN `Table C` USING `cID`;

Comment: I would like to thank you for your response. After writing my initial response I took another look at my query, and tried to make it look more like it seemed it should. In doing so I solved my mistake using the query I posted above and will re-post in an answer thread.