# Mysql. Select data from 3 different tables based on column from 1 table

Tags: mysql, select, join

Here is what I want to do:

I have 3 tables: musicItems, photoItems, textItems
Each table has different columns.

```
Table "musicItems" 
  id
  Owner_id
  audioId
  url
  duration

Table "photoItems" 
  id
  albumId
  userId 
  photoId
  url

Table "textItems" 
  id
  msgText
```

And I have one more table

```
"footprints" 
  id
  itemType
  itemId
```

I need to retieve last 30 items from table "footprints" with all properties depending on itemType and itemId. How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql JOIN of four tables with two key tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824389/mysql-join-of-four-tables-with-two-key-tables)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the columns line up (which footpritns column lines up with which musicitems column for instance?) Also, I believe you're looking to perform a LEFT/INNER join (please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html )

Comment: You need to read up on JOIN Syntax:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Could you please post 5 lines of sample related data from each of your table?

Comment: Brad Christie, "footprints" table contains column "itemType" which can be: 1,2 or 3 and it points to table which contains information about item with id = "footprints.itemId"

Comment: Does your "footprints" table, column "ItemType" represent the table the footprint is associated... ec: "MUSIC", "PHOTO", "TEXT", and the footprints column "ItemID" correspond to the ID within the associated "ItemType" table?  Finally, is the Footprints ID column auto incrementing sequence ID for the table?

Answer (score 0):

I have made the assumption that the `ItemType` column contains the table names the `ItemID` refers to

```
SELECT  *
FROM    footprints fp
        LEFT OUTER JOIN musicItems mi ON mi.ID = fp.itemID AND fp.ItemType = 'musicItems'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN photoItems pi ON pi.ID = fp.itemID AND fp.ItemType = 'photoItems'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN textItems ti ON ti.ID = fp.itemID AND fp.ItemType = 'textItems'
LIMIT   30
```